# AKS Containers refusing connection following upgrade

Tags: kubernetes, containers, azure-aks

We have upgraded our AKS to 1.24.3, and since we have, we are having an issue with containers refusing connection.

There have been no changes to the deployed microservices as part of the AKS upgrade, and the issue is occurring at random intervals.

From what I can see the container is returning the error - The client closed the connection.

What I cannot seem to be able to trace is, the connections, within AKS, and the issue is across all services.

Has anyone experienced anything similar and are able to provide any advise?

Answer (score 4):

I hit similar issue upgrading from 1.23.5 to 1.24.3, issue was configuration mis-match with kubernetes load balancer health probe path and ingress-nginx probe endpoints.

Added this annotation to my ingress-nginx helm install command corrected my problem: --set controller.service.annotations."service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path"=/healthz

Comment: Thank you. That saved me several hours debugging.